# restrict sudo user acess to file/folder

Tags: filesystems, sudo, access-control

First, sorry in advance, I know there are a billion of these questions but nothing worked for me...

I got a certain file in a directory that shall not be deleted by a sudo user. I know that sudo is supposed to to everything, that is the point of that group but maybe there is a solution

I was thinking about restricting the types of commands sudo can do (in the /etc/sudoers file) but first, it would not really solve anything, and second, it didnt work somehow by using the following example:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL, !/usr/bin/rm
```

I tried using different groups, my username, etc., and I could not even restrict a command for my own user

In summary, is there any way I can prevent a sudo users to type certain commands such as rm -rf name_of_folder instead of preventing the access to the entire rm command or any other solution? Maybe it is even possible to ask for a password when typing a certain command?

Comment: You'd need to use SELinux. See here: https://blog.siphos.be/2015/07/restricting-even-root-access-to-a-folder/

Comment: You will also need to restrict access to `unlink` and `link -f` for the obvious ways to overwrite the files.  Next you'll need to restrict editors to prevent deleting the file's contents. You also will have to watch out for `cp /dev/null ...` and `truncate`. The list goes on. `sudo` is good for allowing certain access but is very bad at disallowing operations. There are so many ways in Linux/Unix to make a certain operation happen that you really cannot prevent a bad operator.\

Answer (score 0):

> In summary, is there any way I can prevent a sudo users to type certain commands such as rm -rf name_of_folder

Nope, because you can only express simple matching against command and args in `sudoers`, and it's very easy for users to escape them. For instance they could try `rm -v foo`, `rm -- foo`, `rm foo -r` and so on. It would depends on the exact interface of every command and sudo does not understand them.

> instead of preventing the access to the entire rm command or any other solution?

That's the usual alternative. You prevent access to `rm`, but you provide access to your own restricted command, usually a shell "wrapper" around the targe command.

But it's hard to write a restricted command right, and it's a high security risk. I suggest you start with a command with no args, which makes sure it ignores stdin and its environment, and give root access to your users thru `sudoers`. Then maybe add 1 arg and be very pedantic about its interpretation, especially if it's a path.

The most basic restricted command would be a `/usr/local/bin/restricted_rm` like :

```
#!/bin/sh

exec </dev/null
/usr/bin/env -i rm -rf /absolute/path/to/folder
```

Try to adjust your process/interface with your users to see if such a simple script can do the trick, it's worth it. Otherwise you've been warned with more complex "filtered" restricted commands, it's a serious security hazard. Even if you know what you're doing. Been there.

Comment: A script would definitely suffice. But unfortunately I dont understand the script, I am not very sophisticated and I dont know what to look for in the Internet. In addition, why didnt my restriction work in the sudoers file? If this works, maybe I can use chattr +i and restrict the access to that command?

Comment: @Newton_co *A script would definitely suffice.*  Not really.  They're almost impossible to get secure.  For example, does the shell script currently posted source startup or termination scripts such as `.bashrc`?  If so, those files can contain *any* commands the user wants.  And the currently-posted script looks vulnerable to environment attacks via `LD_PRELOAD`, `IFS`, and `PATH` environment variables.  And those are just off the top of my head. Trying to give someone "just a little bit of root" is **HARD**.  Have you even thought about someone simply renaming your file with `mv` yet?

Comment: @AndrewHenle where do you learn all this? Do you have a book recommendadion. And regarding my problem: it is a very special application,  this file will not be renamed and the simplest solutions, such as a script, works in my case. I just dont know how to apply it

Comment: Totally seconding @AndrewHenle